# How to use PHPhotoLibrary like ALAssetsLibrary

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, alassetslibrary, photosframework

For iOS9, `ALAssetsLibrary` is deprecated. So how to change it as `PHPPhotoLibrary` instead of `ALAssets`?

```
if (RecordedSuccessfully && recording == NO) {
    //----- RECORDED SUCESSFULLY -----
    NSLog(@"didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL - success");
    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    if ([library videoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum:outputFileURL])
    {
        [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:outputFileURL
                                    completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error)
         {
             if (error)
             {

             }
         }];
    }
```

// i have tried this, but didnt work

```
[[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{

        PHAssetChangeRequest* createAssetRequest = [PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromVideoAtFileURL:outputFileURL];

        NSParameterAssert(createAssetRequest);
    }
                                      completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {}];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
// Save to the album
   __block PHObjectPlaceholder *placeholder;

    [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
        PHAssetChangeRequest* createAssetRequest = [PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromVideoAtFileURL:outputFileURL];
        placeholder = [createAssetRequest placeholderForCreatedAsset];

    } completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
        if (success)
        {
           NSLog(@"didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL - success for ios9");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
        }
    }];
```

Comment: this is the correct answer, you should mark it as such :)

Comment: How about assetURL? How can I get url after saving?

Comment: How is `sharedPhotoLibrary` declared?

Comment: A good way to replace the assetURL from ALAssetLibrary is to use the PHObjectPlaceholder. From the example above just use placeholder.localIdentifier this will give you the path to the item in your photo library. This is from my experience playing around with it. @Besat