# In PHPhotoLibrary, how to know whether video file can save on iPhone or not

Tags: ios, objective-c, phphotolibrary

I'm changing over from ALAssetsLibrary to PHPhotoLibrary and want to know whether or not video file can save or not.
In **ALAssetsLibray**, you know, we could know it before start saving video file with the API

```
- (BOOL)videoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum:(NSURL *)videoPathURL;
```

Does anyone knows the substitute API for *videoAtPathIsCompatibleWIthSavedPhotoAlbum* in **PHPhotoLibrary** ?

Or do you know the exact error code which means that a video file cannot save on the iOS device ?

My code for saving video file is like below,

```
- (void)saveVideoFile:(NSURL *)videoURL completion:(savePhotoFileCompletion)completion
{
    [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
            PHAssetChangeRequest *assetChangeRequest;
            assetChangeRequest = [PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromVideoAtFileURL:videoURL];

            PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest *assetCollectionChangeRequest =
                [PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest changeRequestForAssetCollection:self.assetCollection];
            [assetCollectionChangeRequest addAssets:@[ [assetChangeRequest placeholderForCreatedAsset] ]];

        }

        completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *_Nullable error) {
            DBGLog(@"success=%@, error=%@", (success ? @"YES" : @"NO"), error);
            completion(success, error);
        }];
}
```

I found the question talking about the same issue.

[How to use PHPhotoLibrary like ALAssetsLibrary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33500266/how-to-use-phphotolibrary-like-alassetslibrary)

But it doesn't refer to the exact answer.

Answer (score 4):

I asked my question to Apple with TSI.
And their answer is to use the following API

```
AVAsset *avAsset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath]];
BOOL canSaveVideo = [avAsset isCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum];
```

It seemed that I could get the correct compatibility.

One important point it that PHPhotoLibrary can save the video even if the value of `canSaveVideo` is NO.

Thank you.